# What is the radius of the circumference circumscribed in the $ABCD$ quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry

A quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in a circle of radius $R.$ It is known that $\measuredangle ADB = 90^\circ$ and the distance between the centers of the circles inscribed in the triangles $ADB$ and $BCD$ is $6.$ Calculate $R.$

My progress:

I made the drawing. There are many possibilities to draw but I made one side being the diameter of the circumscribed circumference.

$$LN = 6\\
LO \perp AB\\
PO =\frac{AP}{2}\\
\triangle BCD \text{ (isosceles)}\implies CP \perp BD
$$

I couldn't but useful relations

[image]

Comment: How can you prove that C , N, P  are colinear?

Comment: The quadrilateral is _inscribed_ in the circle. The circle is _circumscribed_ about the quadrilateral. (I edited accordingly.)

Comment: The information provided does not seem sufficient

Comment: @MathLover..I thought so as well..

Comment: You can draw in GeoGebra and see. For the same $R$, you can easily come up with two different values of distance between incenters

Comment: Do they provide any answer?

Comment: ACB the options are: $6, ~3\sqrt2.~ 5\sqrt2,~ 6\sqrt2~ and ~6\sqrt3$

Comment: Are you sure that they say the distance between the centres of only the inscribed circles is 6? If the distances between each two of three circles are 6, there will be an answer.

Comment: @ACB Always post exactly as the original question is. It may be that sometimes there is a problem in the statement... If it goes as you say, will the answer be among the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let:

Radius of circumcircle is R

Radius 0f Circle center on N: ($=r_1)$

that Of center on L:($r_2$)

$\angle NLG=\alpha$

and $\angle LON=45^o$

Considering the figure, draw a tangent from G on circle $r_2$ to touch it at H. $GH\bot LH$ also $LH\bot LO$ and $LO\bot AB$ in this way quadrilateral OHGL is parallelogram and $LG=OH$ also:

$ HN=GN=r_2 \cos 45^o=\frac {r_2}{\sqrt 2}$

$OH=2\times r_2 \cos 45^o=r_2\sqrt 2$

$LG=OH=r_2\sqrt 2=r_2+r_1$

$\Rightarrow ON=3 r_2 \cos 45^o= \frac{3r_2}{\sqrt 2}$

$$\sin \alpha=\frac{\frac{r_2}{\sqrt 2}}{LN=6}=\frac16 \sqrt{\frac{72-r_2^2}2}$$

$2r_2 \cos 45^o=6\cos \alpha=6\times\frac16 \sqrt{\frac{72-r_2^2}2}$

which gives $r_2\approx 3.9$

$ LG=r_1+r_2=LN\cdot \cos \alpha$

$\Rightarrow r_1=2\times 3.9 \cos 45^o-3.9\approx 1.4$

$R\approx ON +r_1=\frac{3\times 3.9}{\sqrt 2}+1.4\approx 9.7$

If you apply Euler's theorem you finally get this equation:

$2R^2-2(r_1+r_2)-2 ON\cdot LN \cos 45^o=LN^2=6^2=36$

$2 R^2-2\times 5.3 R=36+61=97$

which gives $R\approx 9.8 $